# Django ORM difference() not working correctly with querysets with ArrayAgg

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to get the difference between two querysets which have been grouped by using ArrayAgg. My queries look like this:

```
yesterday_feeds = (
    Summary.objects.filter(started_at__date=yesterday)
        .values("client_feed__xml_url")
        .annotate(
        found_pms=ArrayAgg("found_property_managers",
                                         distinct=True, filter=Q(
                found_property_managers__isnull=False))
    )
)
```

And the result:

```
[{'client_feed__xml_url': 'someurl_1', 'found_pms': [7, 10, 11]}, {'client_feed__xml_url': 'some_url_2', 'found_pms': [380]}]
```

The other query:

```
today_feeds = (
    Summary.objects.filter(started_at__date=today)
        .values("client_feed__xml_url")
        .annotate(
        found_pms=ArrayAgg("found_property_managers",
                                         distinct=True, filter=Q(
                found_property_managers__isnull=False))
    )
)
```

And it's result:

```
[{'client_feed__xml_url': 'someurl_1', 'found_pms': [7, 10]}, {'client_feed__xml_url': 'some_url_2', 'found_pms': []}]
```

I'd like to get the values for a given xml_url which are present in yesterday_feeds but not in today_feeds:

```
>>> yesterday_feeds.difference(today_feeds)
[[{'client_feed__xml_url': 'someurl_1', 'found_pms': [11]}, {'client_feed__xml_url': 'some_url_2', 'found_pms': [380]}]]
```

But what I get is just yesterday_feeds queryset:

```
[{'client_feed__xml_url': 'someurl_1', 'found_pms': [7, 10, 11]}, {'client_feed__xml_url': 'some_url_2', 'found_pms': [380]}]
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The result is completely _correct_, you appear to have some misunderstanding about what `difference` does. It uses the `EXCEPT` clause in SQL which is described as: "EXCEPT returns all rows that are in the result of query1 but not in the result of query2." so the result you see is completely correct...

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you for your insight.